# In which order to add risers and treads to stairs?

Tags: technique

I've read many guides that show that risers are added to stairs before the treads. What is the reason or does it not matter?

Comment: Do you buy chance have a link or resource to reference that talks about what you are saying? Also I am not sure if this might be a better fit on DIY.SE since it is about stairs construction

Comment: As @Matt already stated, this should probably be in the DIY.SE, [and it is](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28690/how-should-stair-treads-and-risers-be-assembled) :) Mathias Wandel also has [a guide](https://woodgears.ca/home/stair_treads.html) for re-doing stairs. As far as i know he doesn't adress your issue, but maybe you can gain some knowledge that will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments,  the link that Stoppal provided is perfect

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: We welcome design considerations of all woodworking projects here, whether the project is part of a house or not. So while this question is certainly valid on DIY.SE, it's also valid here.

Answer (score 3):

Risers generally go first *when installed in situ* because the risers couldn't be fitted after the treads are in place, or not as easily. Sometimes it is *all* risers first, then the treads, sometimes it's riser, tread, riser, tread etc. working from the bottom to the top.

Of course whether you're retrofitting an existing staircase or building a new staircase makes a big difference, since in a new build you're doing the assembly work sideways with the stringer flat on the floor. In this case riser and tread can be fitted together (with any reinforcing blocks) and then installed as a piece.

When doing a rebuild whether you have access to the undersides of the stairs, or not, is also a factor. Various design specifics may also affect whether you work top-down or bottom-up, since in some cases the design forces you to work in a specific direction because of how the treads and risers fit together (housing joints or dados, interlocking rebates/rabbets or plain butt joints throughout).

Some illustrations will help clarify some of the above, see how in both of these traditional designs it would be impossible to fit the risers if the treads were fixed in place:

[image: Traditional stair cross-sections]

<sup>Source: **Carpentry & Joinery**, Frederick C. Webber, 1898</sup>

Note that since the tread on one step must be in place before the next riser in ascending order you're forced to work from the bottom upwards. Despite how this may sound this is still riser-first, since the bottom riser would be the first part fitted :-)

Now see how in this modern stair you must have access to the underside in order to do the work:

[image: Modern stair design]

In this case when originally built I'm sure the risers and treads would be assembled and then installed as a unit.

Note how difficult it would be to replace one or more treads on a design like this, impossible in some cases without rebuilding the entire staircase!

Comment: To clarify things, I'm building a very small staircase from scratch and have already prepared the stringers.  I take the point from a repair perspective of risers first but for my purposes, I can flip the assembly around at this point in time. This means I like the point of assembling the riser-tread piece together as a unit.